# How do I write a function that will insert random values into a stack of integers?

Tags: c#

Write a function that accepts an integer as its only argument. Throw an exception of the integer is less than one. The function should
create a stack of integers (enforce the type stored in the stack by using generics!),
populate the stack with the random integers (random within the range 0 to 99), such that the stack holds a count of random integers equal to the argument passed in, and
return the stack.

this is my code so far, i'm new to this. If you can help, i will be pleased

```
Console.WriteLine("ENTER A NUMBER");
int arg = Int16.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

if (arg < 1)
{
    try
    {
    }
    catch (System.IndexOutOfRangeException e)
    {
        throw new System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value must be more than 1");
    }

    Stack<int> mystack = new Stack<int>(arg);
    Random rd = new Random();
    if( arg > 1)
    {

        int rndnum = rd.Next(arg);
        arg = mystack.Pop();
        return

    }
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: what is the problem with your current code?

Comment: You need to tag this as homework if it is.  Also you may want to ask a specific question.  No-one does code reviews here.

Comment: Do you have a specific question?  Is there a problem with what you have?  Please don't make us have to work out what your problem is.

Comment: @Jeff: I think the OP's core problem is a homework deadline. Isn't tomorrow a Monday?

Comment: @Henk: Perhaps, but even then, if there's a question to be asked, it has to be said.  Dumping code and expecting people to find out what is wrong with it is not an effective questioning technique.  If we could get this message out to everyone who asks questions like this, Stack Overflow will be better off.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to start with is a function - "*Write a function that accepts an integer as its only argument.*"

To me, that looks like:

```
ReturnType MyFunction(int argument) { ... }
```

...where `ReturnType` is the return type of the function, and `...` needs to be replaced by an actual implementation.  Later in the instructions it tells you the return type should be a stack of integers.  So...

```
Stack<int> MyFunction(int argument) { ... }
```

You may need Console.ReadLine() to gather input, to send to the function.  But nothing in the description says the function should read input from the console. So to me, that implies the Console.ReadLine() ought to be outside the function.

Give that a think, turn the crank again, and post an update.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this piece of code means: "do nothing and if there is an exception of nothing throw another exception"

```
try
{
}
catch (System.IndexOutOfRangeException e)
{
    throw new System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value must be more than 1");
}
```

While what you need is "Throw an exception of the integer is less than one.". So you must `throw` a `new` `Exception` if the number is lower than `1`.

When you achieve the behavior mentioned above you won't need

```
Stack<int> mystack = new Stack<int>(arg);
Random rd = new Random();
if( arg > 1) // to check if the argument is invalid
{            // the program shouldn't execute if
}            // arg is lower than 1
```

After that, look at the reference of `Random`, you said you need a number between `0` and `99`

```
rd.Next(arg); // this is not generating a number between 0 and 99
```

Also, you shouldn't be removing elements from the stack, you have to `add` elements

```
mystack.Pop(); // removing from stack
```

And return the stack afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

The catch block will never be entered. There is nothing in the try block and the program won't crash => it won't go to catch.